# What set is this minifigure from?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I found this minifigure in an unmarked box, but do not know what set it came from.

[image: Minifigure wearing pirate hat, with smiley face, gray and yellow tech torso, blue arms, and gray and yellow legs.]

Comment: It looks like it came from a dog's mouth. Poor minifig has seen some hard times.

Answer (score 8):

Legs and torso are from a Unitron figure: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=sp048

[image]

The red bandana has appeared in almost 100 sets (often [pirate-themed](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=61.688)), while the head and hands are generic and could be from any number of sets as well.